# FPU in STM32F4 Processors

Tags: assembly, floating-point, embedded, cpu-registers, stm32

**Relevant Specs**:

- STM32F407IG Processor with FPv4-SP FPU (Cortex M4F);
- STM32F40G-EVAL dev board;
- IAR Embedded Workbench - ARM, v6.50

**Question**: How might I programmatically turn the FPU on prior to FP computations, and turn it off again when finished?

- IAR EWARM provides the ability to turn off/on the FPU in project options prior to building
- In `SystemInit()`, which is called prior to `main`, the following code is executed:

  ```
  #if (__FPU_PRESENT == 1) && (__FPU_USED == 1)    
  SCB->CPACR |= ((3UL << 10*2)|(3UL << 11*2));    /* set CP10 and CP11 Full Access */
  #endif
  ```

  Note that this sets CPACR bits [23:20] to 1. This is required, or else a HardFault IRQ will be called upon the next FPU assembler instruction. ***But does disabling this have any additional implications, such as lower power-consumption, etc, or does this register just police the coprocessor (FPU)?***
- If there is no further implication, then perhaps "turning it off", via CPACR, doesn't accomplish anything, indicating that FPU only draws additional power while executing FPU Instruction Set commands.

  Thanks,

Comment: You should be able to determine this from the data sheet, or by measuring the actual current consumption of the device.

Comment: It is a microcontroller so it likely powers down/clock starves the fpu to save power.  Have you tried it yet to check power consumption?

Comment: Yes, I've run CMSIS DSP tests using Q31 and F32 on different iterations. For each format, I re-built, flashed, and measured current consumption with FPU on, and FPU off. It seems that there is only an additional power draw if the FPU is actually being utilized (e.g. while F32 DSP functions are called). The Q31 build was drawing the same current, even with the FPU on. I am not convinced from these tests alone, however, that this would always be the case. And I did not catch any assembler commands trying to power down any clks.

Comment: Also, when the main clk was configured to be the board's High-Speed External, there was **no/little additional power draw measured across MCU_VDD (processor supply)** for FPU vs Q31, both FPU On and Off. When the main clk is configured to be High-Speed INTERNAL however, the difference is considerable.

Comment: It has been a long time, but do you still have the results? I have been looking for some data like this but the link no longer works. Thanks.

Comment: @ChiZhang, sure, reposting: [These are my results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvi9kdz4dtpysrb/fpu_results.png?dl=0) using the HSI clk (which properly captures the FPU's pwr consumption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a Usage Fault (or promoted Hard Fault if Usage Faults are disabled) if an instruction attempts to access a coprocessor (like the FPU) and it is disabled. You can inspect the NOCP bit in the Usage Fault Status Register to see if that is the source of the fault. You can then use the Usage Fault as a trap to enable the FPU and resume execution.

My approach would be as follows:

- Enable FPU in IAR project (think will allow IAR to target the FPU)
- Enable FPU at startup (you want it enabled until your fault handler is configured)
- Disable FPU for power savings once the fault handler is configured and enabled.
- On fault (usage or hard fault) inspect the NOCP bit in the Usage Fault Status Register.
- If NOCP is set, enable the FPU, return from fault.
- In the background application, disable FPU when you complete your calculations or use a timer to disable it periodically.

If you use an RTOS, you will need to look at their implementation of context switching, as it may also attempt to hook into the Usage Fault/Hard Fault if it uses lazy stacking (see reference) rather than active stacking.

One thing to consider if power is a concern would be whether floating point is needed. If you can represent your number space as fixed point in a 32-bit value, using fixed point math instead of floating point may result in overall lower power consumption, as there would be no overhead to enabling/disabling the FPU or stacking FPU registers on context switch. The trade-off is that the fixed point math may be a few instructions longer per operation

Reference: [ARM AppNote 298](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0298a/DAFJBFJF.html)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Yes, utilizing the FPU does seem require more instantaneous power draw, though the results I posted (in the comments above) indicate that the speed/power trade-off is a worthy one for my given use-case, resulting in fewer mAh overall. Also, there does't seem to be any overhead in enabling/disabling it other than masking one register at startup. I'm using bare-metal, so I suppose I don't yet have to worry about context switching. Thx again